# php array and array sum not returning right value

Tags: php, arrays, e-commerce

When i call this function on my webpage it should echo out the total value of the products in your shopping cart, But it only echo's out  the value of the product with highest product id. Instead of the sum of these values combined.

```
function total_price() {

    $total = 0;
    global $link;
    $ip = getIp();
    $sel_price= "select * from cart where ip_add='$ip'";
    $run_price= mysqli_query($link, $sel_price);

    while($p_price=mysqli_fetch_array($run_price))  {
        $pro_id = $p_price['id'];
        $pro_price = "select * from products where id='$pro_id'";
        $run_pro_price = mysqli_query($link, $pro_price);
        while ($pp_price = mysqli_fetch_array($run_pro_price)){
            $product_price = array($pp_price['prijs']);
            $values = array_sum($product_price);
            $total = number_format((float)$values, 2, ',', '');  
        }
    }
    echo "&euro; " .$total;

}
```

Comment: You're creating an array with one price in it, then using `array_sum()` on it. So the sum is just the value of that one element. You're not adding to the previous rows.

Comment: Why don't you just use `SELECT SUM(prijs) AS total` in the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason to use `array_sum`. The sum of an array with one element is just the value of that element. You would use `array_sum` if you were pushing each price onto the array, and then calculating the sum at the end of the loop. But you can just add to the total value each time through the loop, so there's no need to do that.

```
    while ($pp_price = mysqli_fetch_array($run_pro_price)){
        $values += $pp_price['prijs'];
    }
}
$total = number_format((float)$values, 2, ',', '');  
echo "&euro;" . $total;
```

You could also do everything in a single query:

```
$sel_total = "SELECT SUM(prijs) AS total
                FROM cart 
                JOIN products ON cart.id = product.id
                WHERE ip_add = '$ip'";
$res = mysqli_query($sel_total);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
$total = number_format($row['total'], 2, ',', '');
echo "&euro;" . $total;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$total += number_format((float)$values, 2, ',', '');
```

should work

Comment: You should use `number_format` AFTER calculating the total.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function total_price() {
    $values = 0;
    $total = 0;
    global $link;
    $ip = getIp();
    $sel_price= "select * from cart where ip_add='$ip'";
    $run_price= mysqli_query($link, $sel_price);

    while($p_price=mysqli_fetch_array($run_price))  {
        $pro_id = $p_price['id'];
        $pro_price = "select * from products where id='$pro_id'";
        $run_pro_price = mysqli_query($link, $pro_price);
        while ($pp_price = mysqli_fetch_array($run_pro_price)){
            //$product_price = array($pp_price['prijs']);
            //this will cumulate sum 
            $values += $pp_price['prijs'];
            //$total = number_format((float)$values, 2, ',', '');  
        }
    }
    //this will format result
    $total = number_format((float)$values, 2, ',', '');
    echo "&euro; " .$total;

}
```

btw why dont you try using JOIN statement???

Comment: Get rid of `array_sum`. It should just be `$values += $pp_price['prijs']`.